# What does "I want him to know" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> I want **him** to know

I can't understand, why "him" stays between 2 verbs. Does it mean "I want that he will know" or something else? Maybe this phrase has special meaning. I'll be thankful so much, if you give me some rule about it.

Comment: Yes, you guessed correctly. The intention of the speaker is for some other person ("him") to receive some information, to get to know some fact.

Answer (score 1):

We can make statements of desire that someone or something does something by using the verb "want", followed by a name, pronoun, or identifying phrase, and then the infinitive (base form) of the verb, or a verb phrase:

I want him to know the truth.
I want her to go.
She wants Peter to come.
You want me to go home.
We want the car to start.
I want my mother to stop drinking.
He wanted his father to be happy.
We will want them to see the film.